# How does the modern idea of metric tensor relate to the historic idea of Gauss?

Tags: differential-geometry

Gauss envisioned the metric as a function which takes coordinates of two "nearby points" on the surface and gives out a number ( see eg Needham 2021), and, the modern idea of the metric involves a function which takes in two vectors at the tangent space at a point and spits out a number.

How does the modern idea of a metric tensor connect to the one of gauss with infinitesimals? They seem like two conceptually different things.

Comment: The metric gives an inner product on the tangent spaces. Given two points in a manifold, you can connect them by a smooth path. This path has tangent vectors at each point, which you can then use to write down an arc-length formula on your manifold in a way analogous to what you do in Euclidean space, treating your tangent vectors as 'infinitesimal lengths.' The distance between two points is then the infimum of these arc lengths over all such smooth curves. If this doesn't clear it up, I can spell some of this out in an answer later.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, Gauss already used the (modern) metric tensor for parametrized surfaces in the Euclidean three dimensional space, which was then called [the first fundamental form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_fundamental_form), and denoted with a matrix $\begin{pmatrix} E & F \\  F & G\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: That makes sense but the idea of metric tensor was for **nearby points** not arbitrary points. I'm not sure how gauss even meant near so there's thar @A.ThomasYerger

Comment: I've never read Gauss, so I am not sure either. The idea of abstract manifolds will not be invented for over a century, so I am not completely sure that 'nearby,' can be given a completely rigorous meaning in the historical context. I also have the vague impression that maybe Spivak spells this out in his books on differential geometry.

Comment: Instead of quoting Needham, you should be quoting Gauss.

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom If you define the derivative you're using some open neighborhood of a point to do so. You didn't escape the locality, you just assumed it.

Comment: I would guess that Gauss' idea would be realizable using [this approach](https://arxiv.org/abs/1405.0984). Here, tangent vectors at $x$ are essentially represented as points infinitesimally close to $x$.

Comment: [This](https://www2.tsuda.ac.jp/suukeiken/math/suugakushi/sympo29/29_ishibashi.pdf) is probably of interest

Comment: Yes, volume 2 of Spivak’s 5-volume magnum opus contains translations of Gauss and interpretations in modern language.

Answer (score 0):

In modern mathematics, infinitesimals are either part of non-standard analysis (which I know little about) or hand-wavey intuition (which I know a little about). I'm going with the second one.

What are tangent vectors? There are several common, interchangeable definitions. We shall use

> A tangent vector at $p$ is an equivalence class on the set of differentiable curves $\Bbb R\to M$ (where $M$ is our surface) with $0\mapsto p$, where two curves $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ are equivalent iff $\gamma_1'(0)=\gamma_2'(0)$

Now say we have two tangent vectors and an infinitesimal $dt$. Take a representative curve for each of the two vectors, and evaluate them both at $dt$. This will give two points infinitesimally close to $p$. These are the Gaussian tangent vectors you're taking about. This is the connection between the two notions.

In short: Take the modern tangent vector, move along it for an infinitesimal amount of time, and you get an infinitesimal displacement.

Going the other way (from a point $q$ infinitesimally close to $p$, to a modern tangent vector) is "merely" a matter of finding a curve that goes from $p$ to $q$ in the time $dt$.